# how to make alias with quotes

Tags: linux, shell, alias

I tried to make alias with quotes as following:

```
alias myalias='ps -ef | grep tomcat | kill -9 `awk {'print $2'}`'
```

but as you can see i already have `'` in awk

so i tried to replace

```
awk {'print $2'}
```

with

```
awk {"print $2"}
```

but then strange things happen to me when i run this alias, ie, the console window get closed...
how can i make this alias work

Comment: It is customary to put awk's {braces} inside the quotes, but not strictly required. awk requires its program to be a single command line argument. You could write, if you were sufficiently  perverse: `awk {print\ \$2}`

Comment: What's wrong with `killall tomcat`?

Comment: Or `pkill tomcat`...

Comment: `killall` doesn't always do what you think it does, so I think it's a bad habit to get into. (On some unixes, it is the equivalent of `shutdown`...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a function instead of an alias avoids most of these quoting problems:

```
myfn() { ps -ef | awk '/tomcat/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9; }
```

If you're using awk, don't need grep.

Or, stick with a function and avoid almost all the work you're doing:

```
alias myalias='pkill -9 -f tomcat'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can "glue" single quotes with double quotes :

```
alias myalias='ps -ef | grep tomcat | kill -9 `awk {'"'"'print $2'"'"'}`'
```

Here is an interesting reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/escaping-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings

However, there are simpler solutions to kill a process instead of using multiple pipes or additional single quotes (Cf others answers). Here i was just trying to answer your initial question, keeping your logic.

Comment: Or you can use a backslash to escape them.

Comment: @Jenny D Tried to escape them with backslash but didn't worked : `unexpected EOF....`

Comment: @JennyD, you cannot escape single quotes in a single quoted string. `x='foo\'bar'` does not work. You have to do something like `x='foo'\''bar'`. Ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes

Answer (score 4):

Here are the essentials for alias quoting:

```
alias x='echo dollar sign: \$ "single quote: '\'' backslash: \\ double quote: \"."'
$ alias x
alias x='echo dollar sign: \$ "single quote: '\'' backslash: \\ double quote: \"."'
$ x
dollar sign: $ single quote: ' backslash: \ double quote: ".
```

There is very little that cannot be done, virtually anything that can be typed on the **bash** command line can be put into an **alias**.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running these multiple pipes, use arguments to `ps` to get only the pid to start with:

```
alias killtc='kill `ps -C tomcat -o pid=`'
```